# Spring Data Elasticseach: How to create Completion object with multiple weights?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have managed to build a working autocomplete service using Elasticsearch with Spring Boot, but I can't assign different weights for my autocomplete sentences.

While I am building the `Completion` object (`org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.completion.Completion`) I am using the standard constructor and next, I am assigning the weight to the object, for example (I am using Kotlin)

```kotlin
val completion = Completion(arrayOf("Sentence one", "Second sentence"))
completion.weight = 10

(...)

myEntity.suggest = completion
```

what produces the following JSON for Elasticsearch

```json
{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Sentence one", "Second sentence" ],
        "weight" : 10
    }
}
```

But, according to the Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) I would like to achieve something like this

```json
{
    "suggest" : [
        {
            "input": "Sentence one",
            "weight" : 10
        },
        {
            "input": "Second sentence",
            "weight" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible with `spring-data-elasticsearch`? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment the second case is currently not supported by Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Both JSON you show are valid, the first one is for multiple inputs that all have the same weight, the second one is for multiple inputs, when ich input has a different weight.

Please file an issue in [Spring Data Elasticsearch Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES) to add support for the `Completion` object to support this case.